# Group cohomology with coefficients in a chain complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let us suppose that I'm in the following situation: I have a chain complex $(C,\partial)$ and say a finite group $G$ acting over $C$ up to homotopy, meaning that for each  $g \in G$ I have a self chain homotopy equivalence $g_\#:C\to C$ such that $h_\# \circ g_\#\simeq(f\circ g)_\#$, where $\simeq$ is a chain homotopy.

If $\partial=0$ the situation would collapse to the one of a group acting over $C$ (simply a module in this case) and I could consider the group cohomology of $G$ with coefficients in $C$. So my question is:

> Is there a meaningful notion of cohomology of $G$ with coefficients in a chain complex?

PS: of course I can take the homology and get a proper action of $G$ on $H_*(C)$ but I find this boring somehow.

Comment: Yes if the action is strict: either use the bar construction or resolve it as a bicomplex and totalize that. You get a spectral sequence $H_*(G; H_*(C)) \implies H_*(G;C)$. This is the usual equivariant homology spectral sequence when $C = C_*(X)$ for a G-space $X$. If not, I can't imagine you can do anything unless you can make this into a "coherent group action" (recording the homotopies of homotopies between various things, etc), in which case the bar construction story is much the same but a bit more complicated.

Comment: To add to what Mike Miller, try to make the action into  homotopy coherent one first.  Often that tells you a lot about the (geometric) situation involved.  If you cannot make the action coherent that in itself is interesting information and any obstructions you obtain will themselves be useful.

Comment: Do you mean to write $h_* \circ g_* \simeq (hg)_*$ at the end of the first paragraph? There's $f,g$ and $h$ at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

Given your interest in Floer theory, I can't resist mentioning recent work of Hendricks, Lipshitz, and Sarkar, where they describe the equivariant homology of a chain complex with a *coherent* group action, and apply it to define equivariant Floer homology without the need for a $G$-invariant perturbation.

To describe what a coherent group action is, consider the following picture: you have an "involution" $\iota$ on the chain complex, so that $\iota^2$ is not the identity, but is homotopic to the identity. Record this homotopy as $H: \iota^2 \to 1$. Then you will not have $\iota H = H \iota$, but these might further be related by a homotopy, $H_2$, ... ultimately you will have constructed an infinite sequence $H_n$ of homotopies which satisfy various relations with $\iota$ and one another.

Their first paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02449), and describes the story for a finite group $G$; the second paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09132), and gives the story for a compact Lie group $G$.

Personally, I find the second paper an easier read: it uses the notion of "homotopy colimit of an $\infty$-category", but everything is very explicit, and they are patient in explaining to the reader what's going on - I found it a joy to read along and learn from. (It also better separates the Floer theory from the homological algebra.) If you'd like to specialize to the finite group case, you can compare to the area around 3.8-3.11 in the first paper.

---

If the $G$-action is strict, this is an easier story. You can either use the bar construction $B(\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z[G], C)$ to obtain a chain complex whose homology is the equivariant homology of $C$, or you could pick a resolution of $C$ by some half-plane bicomplex (where $C$ lives on the $x = -1$ line) and totalize it. (The bar construction is an example of this.)

In all cases there is a spectral sequence $$H_*(G;H_*(C)) \implies H_*(G;C).$$

The discussion for compact Lie groups is (as always) more complicated: instead of the algebra $\Bbb Z[G]$, one must take homology with respect to the dg-algebra $C_*(G;\Bbb Z)$. I won't discuss this unless you really want to know about it.

Comment: Using an $\infty$-category approach more directly  is a neat way. Related ideas were used some time ago by myself with Ronnie Brown, Andy Tonks and Marek Golasinski: Spaces of maps into classifying spaces for equivariant crossed complexes, Indagationes Mathematicae, 8 (1997) 157 - 172. and a later one :Spaces of maps into classifying
spaces for equivariant crossed complexes, II: the non - discrete case, K - Theory, 23, (2001),129 - 155. These do not directly address your question but do discuss homotopy coherence to some extent in a closely related context.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure my answer will be "meaningful" yet but I've been thinking about this and found your question before I was happy about my understanding so I wanted to come back and share my answer. It's going to take a few steps to get to the thing (III.b below) which I believe addresses your question.

**(I.a) A group acting on a module**

A (discrete) group $G$ acting on an $R$-module $M$ is a functor $$\mathcal{C}_G \xrightarrow{\rho} RMod$$
from the groupoid $\mathcal{C}_G$ (category with one object where elements of $G$ induce morphisms and multiplication in $G$ induces composition in $\mathcal{C}_G$) to the category of $R$-modules where the single object $\bullet$ in $\mathcal{C}_G$ is sent to $M$ and each morphism $g$ is sent to an isomorphism $\rho_g: M \to M$.

**(I.b) Group cohomology with values in a module**

Given a (two-sided) group action $\rho$ of $G$ on $M$, we can form the cochain complex which computes group cohomology:

- Cochains $C^p(G, M) = Set(G^p, M)$ are functions $G \times \dots \times G \to M$.
- The boundary map is given by (modulo signs),
  $$\delta f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p+1}) = \rho_{g_1}\cdot f(g_2, \ldots, g_{p+1})  + \left( \sum\limits_{j=1}^p f(g_1, \ldots,g_{j} \cdot g_{j+1}, \ldots, g_{p+1})\right) + f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})\cdot \rho_{g_{p+1}}$$

The reason why $\nabla \circ \nabla = 0$ is due to the ``strictness'' (I'll come back to this) of the action and the associativity of $G$ and the action of $G$ on $M$.

Note that if the right-action $M \times G \to G$ is trivial we recover the [usual notion of group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Definitions) for a given action.

**(II.a) A group acting on a chain complex of modules**

A (discrete) group $G$ acting on a (co)chain complex $(M, d)$ in $Ch^{\bullet}_R$ is a functor $$\mathcal{C}_G \xrightarrow{\rho} Ch^{\bullet}_R$$
from the groupoid $\mathcal{C}_G$ to the category of chain complexes of $R$-modules (morphisms are chain maps) where the single object $\bullet$ in $\mathcal{C}_G$ is sent to $M^{\bullet}$ and each morphism $g$ is sent to a chain map $\rho_g: M^{\bullet} \to M^{\bullet}$.

**(II.b) Group cohomology with values in a complex**

Given a group action $\rho$ of $G$ on $(M^{\bullet}, d)$, we can form the bicomplex:

- Cochains $C^p(G, M^q) = Set(G^p, M^q)$ are functions $G \times \dots \times G \to M^q$.
- A degree $(1,0)$-operator $\delta:C^p(G, M^q) \to C^{p+1}(G, M^q)$:
  $$\delta f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p+1}) = \rho_{g_1}\cdot f(g_2, \ldots, g_{p+1})  + \left( \sum\limits_{j=1}^p f(g_1, \ldots,g_{j} \cdot g_{j+1}, \ldots, g_{p+1})\right) + f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})$$
  which is a differential for the same reasons as above.
- A degree $(0,1)$-operator $d:C^p(G, M^q) \to C^{p}(G, M^{q+1})$
  $$(df)(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})= d\left(f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})\right)$$
  which is a differential since $(M^{\bullet}, d)$ is a complex.

These two differentials commute by our definition of $\rho$ (i.e. $d(\rho_g \cdot m) = \rho_g \cdot d(m)$) and so we have a total differential $D = \delta + d$ and we can call this total complex the group cohomology.

**(III.a) Homotopy group action on a complex**

Note that our strict group action on a complex above $\rho: \mathcal{C}_G \to Ch^{\bullet}_R$ induces a map of simplicial sets under the nerve functor, $\mathcal{N}\rho: \mathcal{N}\mathcal{C}_G \to \mathcal{N}Ch^{\bullet}_R$. If you're not familiar with this, the nerve essentially decorates simplices with composable sequences of morphisms and their compositions in the category and functors send such decorations to each other. However, we were only using degree zero maps in $Ch^{\bullet}_R$ and so we could use the fact that this is a dg-category (I highly recommend [Lurie's Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf) section 1.3.1 for a very down-to-earth account of this dg-stuff, complete with formulas!) and consider its dg-nerve $\mathcal{N}_{dg}Ch^{\bullet}_R$ (the dg nerve of $Ch^{\bullet}_R$ essentially decorates simplices with complexes as vertices, chain maps as edges, homotopies of chain maps as 2-simplices, and so-on).

**Definition:** A *homotopy group action* is a map of simplicial sets
$$\rho: \mathcal{N}\mathcal{C}_G \to \mathcal{N}_{dg}Ch^{\bullet}_R.$$

**Example:** If a homotopy group action $\mathcal{N}\mathcal{C}_G \xrightarrow{\rho} \mathcal{N}_{dg}Ch^{\bullet}_R$ factors through the inclusion of simplicial sets $\mathcal{N}Ch^{\bullet}_R \hookrightarrow \mathcal{N}_{dg}Ch^{\bullet}_R$ then it is a strict group action as in **(II.a)**.

**(III.b) Group cohomology with values in a complex**

Given a homotopy group action $\rho: \mathcal{N}\mathcal{C}_G \to \mathcal{N}_{dg}Ch^{\bullet}_R.$, we can form the complex:

- Cochains $C^p(G, M^q) = Set(G^p, M^q)$ are functions $G \times \dots \times G \to M^q$.
- A degree $(1,0)$-operator $\delta:C^p(G, M^q) \to C^{p+1}(G, M^q)$:
  $$\delta f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p+1}) = \rho_{g_1}\cdot f(g_2, \ldots, g_{p+1})  + \left( \sum\limits_{j=1}^p f(g_1, \ldots,g_{j} \cdot g_{j+1}, \ldots, g_{p+1})\right) + f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})$$
  which is **not** a differential since $\rho_{g_1}\rho_{g_2}$ and $\rho_{g_1\cdot g_2}$ are homotopic by $\rho_{g_1, g_2}: M^{\bullet} \to M^{\bullet -1}$ (i.e. lack of strictness!).
- A degree $(0,1)$-operator $d:C^p(G, M^q) \to C^{p}(G, M^{q+1})$
  $$(df)(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})= d\left(f(g_1, \ldots, g_{p})\right)$$
  which is a differential since $(M^{\bullet}, d)$ is a complex.
- Degree $(i, 1-i)$ operators for $i>1$, $a^{i, 1-i}: C^p(G, M^q) \to C^{p+i}(G, M^{q+1-i})$ given by,
  $$a^{i, 1-i}(f)(g_1, \ldots, g_i, g_{i+1}, \ldots, g_{i+p}) = \pm \rho(g_1, \ldots, g_i) \cdot f(g_{i+1}, \ldots, g_{i+p})$$
  where $\rho(g_{i_1}, \ldots, g_{i_k})$ is the degree $(1-k)$-homotopy decorating the $k$-simplex whose edges are induced by $g_{i_j}$'s and their compositions.
- A total differential $D = \delta + d + a^{\bullet, \bullet}$ of total degree 1 which squares to zero. The two operators $\delta$ and $d$ commute by the fact that each $\rho_g$ is a chain map as governed by edges in the dg-nerve. Then $d$ squares to zero and the rest of the terms in $D^2$ are found in the formula for the dg-nerve.

I'll stop there for now. Hopefully that was interesting for someone. It was interesting when I learned it.

Comment: I wonder whether this definition of homotopy action coincides up to some equivalences with structure of strictly unital $A_\infty$-module over group ring with the standard augmentation.

Comment: @DenisT that's a nice question about structures I'm not very comfortable with. Please keep me posted if you learn an answer